# Read value or return

Tags: javascript

Often writing function's code I need to make sure certain values are defined or I want immediately return false value. But writing whole *if* block feels too much typing. Is it possible to write instead of:

```
function getSomethingByModel(model) {
    var id = model.id;

    if (! id) {
        return;
    }

    // rest of the code
}
```

Something like this:

```
function getSomethingByModel(model) {
    var id = model.id || return;
    // rest of the code
}
```

This is pure aesthetics question, not functional one.

Comment: I would never 'return' in this case, always catch and deal with errors (because this wouldn't happen in a real application)

Comment: I'd write it like `if (!model.id) return false`. Besides that your second snippet is not valid JavaScript, I also find it less obvious what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

To some extent, you can use the `&&` operator to accomplish this and avoid cumbersome `if` statements:

```
function getSomethingByModel(model) {
    var id = model && model.id,
        thing = id && getThingById(id),
        otherThing = thing && getOtherThingFromThing(thing);

    return otherThing || null;  // or alternatively, just   return otherThing;
}
```

If any stage of the process produces a falsey value, the logic will just quickly fall through to the end and return `null` (or the first falsey value encountered if you use the alternative `return` statement above).

Comment: How is this related to the question? o_O

Comment: @newboyhun The question is asking how to concisely handle the situation where you want to prevent execution of the rest of a function's steps when you encounter a value that is null/undefined/falsey. My example shows how to do that.

Comment: No the question is an AESTHETICS question not a 'how to deal with these problems' question.

Comment: @newboyhun Yes, and my answer is an AESTHETICS answer. I think my example is much cleaner than a function that employs 3 `if` statments to accomplish the same outcome.

Comment: Still, his answer is ok and treats the problem well, and looks good to me. Even if the execution doesn't stop right away and does a few other operations, still, I like it.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but related and nice to have in my toolbox. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could define all your properties at the top of the function (or wherever, because hoisting), then use the side-effects of assignment to cause a return. For example:

```
function getSomethingByModel(model) {
    var id; 

    if(!(id = model.id)) return false;
    // rest of the code
}
```